# Angular 5 Build mechanism for very large applications

Tags: angular

We are migrating our entire WEB Part of application to Angular 5 (earlier backbone web-pack build), we are now preparing a framework in Angular 5 by which all future modules can be plugged, our issue is what is the project structure to maintain and also, what is the build mechanism to choose to achieve:
1) Module developers can work independently from different time zones and locations
2) Individual Module can be built and pushed with out rebuilding entire package?( if any such solution)
3) If we need to build entire Angular App for each module / component change what is the fastest way to build ?
4) Our application is very large and have almost 25+ modules with 30+ people working across different time zones and locations

We need great advice on build part especially (versioning,backward compatibility for our Content management etc.)

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: Looks like build and deployment is your primary concern for your situation. What is the existing environment/tooling/infrastructure do you use for this for the existing application that you plan to port?

Comment: how did you managed it finally ???

Comment: we are using Artifactory(jfrog), for private npm management, and we created this project similar to npm model in Angular, where we have 3 npm packages to be included by all new modules 1) core package( custom pipes+services modules etc..) -> then  2) UI UX with branding npm,  and then a menu framework npm - so any new module has to include them in package.json and start building their module